# Process Builder Action Type: Processes Requires SObject Variable

Tags: process-builder, invocablevariable

**BACKGROUND**

I have two custom object which have a *Master-Detail* relationship:

- Credit Note
- Credit Note Line

I have a Process on `Credit Note` which needs to invoke a Process on `Credit Note Line`

But when I select `Action Type` of `Processes` and selected the Invoke-able process I am required to provide a `Process Variable` of type `SObject`.

[image: Action Type Processes]

But there are no valid options available

[image]

Of my three options:

- Created By ID >
- Last Modified By ID >
- Record Type ID >

The first two give me the same options:

- Contact ID >
- Manager ID >
- Profile ID >
- Role ID >

Each of these just leads to a seemingly endless set of further relationship lookups (in reality it went 8 relationships deep before refusing to let me go further)

And the other option `Record Type ID >` give me **no** options.

**QUESTION**

Why do I need to provide this?

What can I provide to make this work?

---

NOTE: I don't want to solve this using a Flow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember using a process on process builder recently, so I don't know the answer to your first question. On the second one, though, I know that it is a UI design issue. When you reference a field on that window you must select the reference field, not the relationship.

Think of it this way: if you were doing this with Account and Contacts, then you'd get two options: `Account Id` and `Account >`. Both are, in theory, the same. But on the UI, the one with the little arrow indicates that you want to select something related to a related account. You want the account reference (the first field) instead. Try to see if you can find the reference field on that list.